# Change CSS property using Jquery on Image

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the Css to opacity 1 when item is clicked.

Following is the code  (html)

```
<a href="#"><img class="<?php if($favorite == 1){ echo 'alreadyfavorite';} else { echo 'addtofavorite';} ?>" id="<?php 
                while($data5=$select5->fetch()){
                echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];
                }
                ?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>
```

Jquery

```
$('.alreadyfavorite').click(function()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');



    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../controllers/deletefavoriteproperties.php',
        data:
        {
            del_id: del_id
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
       $('.alreadyfavorite').css("addtofavorite");   

        }
    });
});
```

neither this

```
$('.alreadyfavorite').css("addtofavorite");
```

nor this

```
$('.alreadyfavorite').css("opacity:1;");
```

is working....

Comment: `$('.alreadyfavorite').css("opacity",1);`

Comment: This is working thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To point out exactly what's wrong, its the way you are using `.css` property.

This is how you are supposed to use it.

```
$('.alreadyfavorite').css("opacity",1);
```

If you are going to change multiple `CSS` properties you can use as below:

```
$('.alreadyfavorite').css({"background-color": "yellow", "opacity":"1"});
```

**EDIT**

There are multiple ways to get `fade` effect. You can either look for `css animations` or you can use `jquery's` `fadeIn` instead of `css`

Below is the working snippet demonstrating both.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fadeInJquery").on('click',function(){
      $("#fadeJquery").fadeIn("slow");
  });
   $(".fadeInCSS").on('click',function(){
      $("#fadeInCSS").css("opacity",1);
  });
});
```

```css
#fadeInCSS{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#fadeJquery{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="fadeInJquery">Fade In Jquery</button>

<div id="fadeJquery">Jquery faded in div</div>

<button class="fadeInCSS">Fade In CSS</button>

<div id="fadeInCSS">CSS faded in div</div>
```

Comment: This is completely fading out the image.

Comment: Updated the answer @DragonFire

Comment: this is simpler for beginners like me to understand

Comment: Great.. Happy coding.. :)